# Firebase and Maps which all libraries need to include?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I have push notification and for that I am going to use Firebase. I also have map to include in my project, for both we are using google play services library. Since the google play services library is a huge one. I only want the specific library for map and firebase. Can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: Here is a link with all ```google-play-services``` libraries. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Answer (score 1):

```
// FOR GOOGLE MAPS
// to use maps modules to your app
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
// for more advanced features to add to your maps
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
```

More detailed steps on [adding a map to an Android app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

```
// FOR FIREBASE
// to use the new firebase cloud messaging/notifications
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
// for firebase analytics (recommended but optional)
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
```

For more available firebase libraries, visit the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries)

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Be sure to [update the IDE and Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html) before using the APIs

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services', this plugin includes all map packages also then why we need separate dependencies like compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
// for more advanced features to add to your maps
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4' and also it is recommended that only include libraries which all are needed, otherwise  size will increase and create some issues. Why we to include this plugin again?

Comment: You need to include this plugin to add the dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. Check out the documentation >> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin